# Is there a verb form of "Extinct"?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

Is there (modern) verb meaning "to cause to become extinct" please? The desired word would have the same root as "extinct".

The closest I could find etymologically was "extinguish", but its usage is archaic according to [this link](http://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-verb-form-of-extinct) and, to me, it sounds like more of a synonym than a word with the same root.

As an example:

> Humans have accidentally *(extinct(v)(past tense))* at least x species in the past 5 years.

To clarify, I am aware of plenty of words that *can* fill the gap. I was specifically looking for a "real" equivalent to "extinct-ify"

Comment: ***Extinguish*** is the related verb:  ***extinct (adj.)* 
early 15c., "extinguished, quenched," from Latin extinctus/exstinctus,*** past participle of extinguere/exstinguere "to put out, quench; go out, die out; kill, destroy" ***(see extinguish)***. Originally of fires; in reference to the condition of a family or a hereditary title that has "died out," from 1580s; of species by 1768. Shakespeare uses it as a verb. Compare extinction. 
http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=extinct&searchmode=none

Comment: Worth mentioning that extinct and extinguish **cannot** be synonyms because one is a noun and one is a verb, therefore they have entirely different definitions and usage.

Comment: If you give an example of how you would use the term  you are looking for in a sentence , we may help you with more options.

Comment: There isn't a single word verb. You say "cause the extinction of" or "cause one's extinction". You can use "lead to" instead of "cause" also.

Comment: @mfoy_, I meant that "extinguish" is a synonym for my desired word "extinct(v)"

Comment: @ermanen, That's the conclusion I had come to before asking here. That's probably worth adding as an answer.

Comment: As far as I'm aware "extinct-ify" isn't a word. You can't have a synonym of something that doesn't exist...

Comment: @mfoy_, I suppose that's technically true. ;) However I think you know what I meant.

Comment: You can find "extinctify" used in Google and there are a very few hits in Google Books but it is very rare.

Comment: _Go extinct_ is the intransitive; I spose _extinguish_ is the causative, but it's not in use that way.

Comment: When Europeans with firearms arrived, they soon *extincted the great auk.

Comment: @Josh61, I have added an example

Comment: *Extinct* as a verb is obsolete and it was used in the sense of *extinguish*.

Comment: _To drive [a species] to extinction_ is frequently used.

Comment: Man has **annihilated** [number] species in the animal kingdom in the last five years. (Who is to say whether it was caused accidentally or not)

Comment: It's not a single word, but I would use *render extinct* in this context: "Humans have accidentally *rendered* at least x species *extinct* in the past 5 years."

Comment: **Extinctify**, and the noun form is **extinctification**, and finally **extinctificationary**, as in _"Good news, everyone! I invented an extinctificationary device to remove all those penguins from inside our air ducts!"_

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As as direct answer to the question, no. Not in a modern way.

I know you're asking for a specific word, but I feel the only way to maintain the correct context and meaning would be to rephrase the whole sentence:

> At least x species in the past 5 years have become extinct accidentally by human activity .

Any other way would look unusual in my opinion.

*edit to add based on comments*

We should probably put accidentally before extinct.

> At least x species in the past 5 years have become accidentally extinct by human activity.

Comment: This is one of the only answers that actually reads the question properly. I didn't want just a list of words that fit the gap, and "no, there isn't" is a perfectly valid answer.

Comment: "accidentally made extinct"?

Comment: That looks unusual anyway. Correct, but still unusual.

Comment: I would write something more like "have unintentionally/accidentally been made extinct by humans..."

Comment: I would prefer to make it clear whether or not you assert that the human activity was in the last 5 years. (Clearly the extinctions were that recent, but are you counting recent extinctions caused by activity from longer ago?) If you are, then "At least x species have accidentally been made extinct by human activity in the past 5 years"; if not, then "In the past 5 years, at least x species have accidentally been made extinct by human activity". Or "...accidentally become extinct because of...".

Answer (score 21):

The biological term for a local extinction is **[extirpation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_extinction)**, which does have a past-verb form, *[extirpated](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/extirpate)*. You can totally say:

```
Humans have accidentally extirpated at least x species in the past 5 years
```

As a biologist, I would add "... species *from this planet*", because otherwise I'm wondering which local area you are referring to.

Answer (score 20):

"Extinguish" is the obvious answer in terms of sharing the same root, but I don't think it holds true in common usage. No one would say, "We extinguished the passenger pigeon." "Exterminate" and "eradicate" are closer, though not perfect.

Comment: Exterminate is what Daleks do. :)

Comment: And Daleks do not accidentally exterminate! Extermination and  exterminating is their raison d'être

Answer (score 15):

The verb **eradicate** could work very well in this context.  But it admittedly does not come from the same root as extinct.

Comment: It's used regularly to describe intentionally causing viruses to become extinct.

Comment: I think eradicate suits quite well. 'Humans accidentally eradicated the yellow-bellied hippo-squirrel population through overfishing their feeding grounds'.

Answer (score 11):

*Extinct* (v.) has existed (obsolete). So the answer is, "no not at the moment." English is not constrained by an official form so dictionaries follow usage and create educational standards. *Extinct* (v) could become proper again simply by being used enough or published by someone reputable enough. Still, most high school students will only encounter it in Henry VIII or Othello. I rather like *extincted*.

Questions of "does this word exist" always give me a pause, because it's rather a bit like putting the cart before the horse. :)

(if any are curious about how it was used I've included the bulk of the OED entry for the obsolete form).

From the definitive source (OED retrieved 6/19/2015) :

> **1. trans. = extinguish v. 1.**
>
> 1483   Caxton tr. J. de Voragine Golden Legende 250/1   T*he blessid laurence had fyue brennynges withoute forthe whiche he al ouercam manly and extyncte them.*
>
> a1513   H. Bradshaw Lyfe St. Werburge (1521) ii. 166   *The feruent great fire extincted was in-dede.*
>
> 1570   J. Foxe Actes & Monumentes (rev. ed.) I. 105/1   *Eugenia..was..put into hoate bathes, which were extincted, and she preserued.*
>
> **2. = extinguish v. 2.**
>
> 1542   A. Borde Compend. Regyment Helth xx. sig. K.i,   *Purslane dothe extynct the ardor of lassyuyousnes.*
>
> ?1555   Coverdale tr. Hope of Faythful Pref. f. iiiiv,   *Not to stir vp gods grace in vs..wer to..extinct the spirite.*
>
> 1556   J. Heywood Spider & Flie vii. 39   *It is more hard, loue to our selues to extinkt.*
>
> **3 a. = extinguish v. 3.**
>
> 1484   Caxton tr. G. de la Tour-Landry Bk. Knight of Tower (1971) ix. 22   *The grete good dedes and abstynence that I dyde quenchyd and estyncted al my synnes.*
>
> 1547   in E. Cardwell Documentary Ann. Church Eng. (1839) I. 42   *They have..utterly extincted and destroyed..all images.*
>
> a1552   J. Leland Itinerary (1712) VIII. 14   *The Name of the Barony of Say is extinctid.*
>
> 1598   F. Meres Palladis Tamia f. 287v,   *One straine of Musicke extincts the pleasure of another.*
>
> 1603   H. Crosse Vertues Common-wealth sig. E4,   *Two contraries, cannot ioyntly hold possession, but one will vtterly extinct the other.*
>
> **3 b**. To put an end to, make void (a law, legal right, status, ordinance). Also, to cancel (a licence, the claim of a creditor). Cf. extinguish v. 3b.
>
> **3 c**. To abolish, suppress (a state of things, custom, institution).
>
> 1531–2   Act 23 Hen. VIII c. 20   *To extinct and make frustrate the paymentys of the said Annates or first fruytes.*
>
> 1540   Act 32 Hen. VIII c. 22 §3   *Many chanteries..ben sins yt time vtterly dissolued and extincted.*
>
> **3 d ...**
>
> **3 e ...**
>
> **Derivatives:** **exˈtincted** *adj.*
>
> a1616   Shakespeare Othello (1622) ii. i. 82   *He may..Giue renewd fire, To our extincted spirits.*
>
> **exˈtincting**   *n.*
>
> 1513   King Henry VIII Let. in J. Strype Eccl. Mem. I. App. i. 3   *Wee..have, for the extincting of the detestable Schisme..entred actual war.*
>
> 1631   J. Weever Anc. Funerall Monuments 113   *For the..vtter extincting of..power and authoritie.*

Comment: *OED* gives "extinct" as an obsolete verb and it was not used in the sense of what OP is asking. OP is asking for a modern verb.

Comment: Fair enough. Edited to make that point. Sometimes I rush to answer the question in the title without seeing the conditions given below. So to the title question the answer is "yes," and to the question beneath it, the answer is "only if you can get something published with it, otherwise, not right now."

Comment: Completely unrelated to the question, but _lassyuyousnes_ is just about the coolest word ever. (It’s _lasciviousness_, in case anyone got lost in the sea of vowels.)

Comment: Re: "extincted": Pfft. Swim, swam, swum, sing, sang, sung, sink, sank, sunk, extinct, extanct, extunct. :-)

Comment: I've seen "extinct" as a verb as late as 2014 (yes last year).

Comment: A comment on: "English is not constrained by an official form so dictionaries follow usage and create educational standards." Perhaps YOUR English is not constrained by an official form but anyone who takes a University exam, writes a job application or works in a publishing house needs to learn the rules of spelling and grammar; the only alternative is to be regarded as illiterate.

Comment: Cuddlyale3: Great point. Let me clarify. In linguistic sciences we sometimes use the terms "official" and "standard" with very specific meanings. "Official" refers to language prescribed by governmental decree or legislation. In contrast, "standard" refers to language prescribed through educational institutions and practices. I believe this is what you mean and we agree. I mean that Standard English in each territory has changed and will continue to change over time. Dictionary editors survey the language in use and update the dictionaries accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

**Extinguish** (https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/extinguish)

> **Etymology**
>
> From Latin extinguo, past participle extinctus (“to put out (what is burning), quench, extinguish, deprive of life, destroy, abolish”), from ex (“out”) + stinguere (“to put out, quench, extinguish”).

Compared to:
**Extinct** (https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/extinct)

> **Etymology**
>
> Recorded since 1432; from Latin extinctus, the past participle of extinguere (“to put out, destroy, abolish, extinguish”), corresponding to ex- + stinguere (“to quench”)

---

Even though it would be a little *awkward* to say "I will extinguish your species" the etymology matches closely enough and the meaning is clear.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean something form the point of view of whatever gets extinct, I'd suggest **die out**, as in species XPTO is under threat of *dying out* if certain decisions aren't made.

Comment: And from the point of view of the cause of the extinction, **wipe out**.

Comment: Also *killed off*.

Comment: *Stamp out*, as well.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen "made extinct" used in textbooks and writing. IE. "Humans have accidentally made extinct at least x species in the past 5 years." or "Humans will accidentally make extinct at least x species in the next 5 years."

Answer (score 0):

What about extirpate? "To remove or destroy totally".
Still not the same root as extinct, but commonly used with regard to threatened and endangered species.

Comment: That is already [an answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/253605/21740). It's a good word, but the same as most of the other answers, it doesn't answer the question. In this case 'no' is the answer.

Answer (score -1):

A behaviorist says *extinguish* when talking about putting a behavior that has been put on extinction.

Comment: Who? Can you explain where you saw or heard this?

Answer (score -1):

I would coin “extinctual” for an adjective describing that which causes extinction.  Our fossil fuel use is extinctual.

We clearly need such a word and lacking such a word we should coin one.  “Extinctify” strikes me as clumsy and is not an adjective, but a verb.  “Extinctificatory” is even more clumsy.

Comment: They're after a word that exists already, I think.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Eliot and welcome to ELU. Your answer however is lacking a few things. My question asks for a verb, and specifically asks for the "real" equivalent of a verb I coined to convey what I was looking for. This answer is a little away from the mark in that you've started introducing adjectives though your answer is stronger than some others in that it focuses on the etymology rather than just plugging the gap.

Comment: And I might suggest "exctincting" as an adjective to mean "a phenomenon which causes extinction" – The (P–Tr) event was the most extincting in planetary history

Answer (score -2):

In Webster's 9th New Collegiate Dictionary,they give extinct as verb transitive. Page number is 440.

Comment: [M-W also gives that entry](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/extinct). It is labelled archaic which means that nobody would recognize that usage nowadays.

Answer (score -2):

The answer is “exterminate” as you can see below.
[image]

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't answer the question. My question asks for a word of the same root, not just a word that fits the gap. `Extinct` has its roots in the Latin word `extinguere - extinguish` whereas `exterminate` has roots in `ex-terminus` meaning "to put outside of the boundary"

Comment: To *kill* someone or something (exterminate) does not mean the same as to *die out* (to be extinct). And an answer consisting only a massive screenshot, which is how it appears on a desktop computer, is not helpful to users who use screen readers.

Comment: Well, pardon me then.