# Opposite of Extinction

Tags: antonyms, semantics, derivational-morphology, antecedents, consequence

***Extinct*** is to ***Extant***; as ***Extinction*** is to ***____________***?

The root words, *extinct* *&* *extant*, are basically polar opposites.

The correct answer would be a technical term that indicates the polar opposite of *extinction*, and follows the same kind of semantic or etymological pattern.

Despite it's ugliness, something like *extantion* would fit the bill, but I can't find any evidence of such a word.

It's possible the word I'm looking for simply doesn't exist, but that seems kind of bizarre considering the amount of scientific literature devoted and/or related to the concept.

Comment: I had to look up "extant" in a dictionary... (and I thought I had a good vocabulary...), but it has a synonym that is easily converted into a noun. Have you tried this? If not, why not? If you have, why doesn't it answer your question?

Comment: Duplicate of [Noun form of “extant”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/267920/noun-form-of-extant)

Comment: Was this multiple choice? Did they suggest anything?

Comment: Perhaps 'extantion' should be coined.

Comment: @JohnGo-Soco That's what I was going for. Sounds off though. Not sure why it's been put on hold, you obviously get it.

Comment: What about reintroduction? It’s not linguistically perfect but it is the literal process by which extinction is reversed.

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey I can see how it's related but not quite the same thing. Interesting though; I like the idea. Thanks for the contribution :)

Answer (score 3):

While *extant* is (roughly) the opposite of *extinct* (the state of [still] existing vs. the state of not existing), I would contend that there isn't an *analogous* opposite to *extinction*:

> [**extinction** [TFD]](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/extinction)
>
> **1a.** The act of extinguishing: *The extinction of the fire took several hours.*
>
> **1b.** The condition of being extinguished: *mourned the extinction of her dreams.*
>
> *(Both from American Heritage Dictionary)*
>
> **1.** The act of making extinct or the state of being extinct
>
> *(From Collins English Dictionary)*

For the first of these senses (the *act of extinguishing/making extinct)* then the opposite is *the act of bringing into existence*.  At least for species, and depending on one's beliefs, you might have:

> [**speciation** [TFD]](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/speciation)
>
> The formation of new biological species through the process of evolution.

or:

> [**creation** [TFD]](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/creation)
>
> 4. The divine act by which, according to various religious and philosophical traditions, the world was brought into existence.

(*Creation*, in a non-religious sense could be used for the *coming-into-existence* of most things, but probably wouldn't be used for species, because of the religious overtones).

For the second sense (*the state of being extinct*), then *survival* (as in [lbf's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/444148/102510)) is probably the closest opposite, although (to me, at least) it's not perfect: *extinction* is a definite thing that has happened; survival is the ongoing state of not yet having been made extinct.

Answer (score 1):

**genesis**

> The origin or mode of formation of something. [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/genesis)

Chosen on the basis that "Extinction" is:

> The state or process of being or becoming extinct [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/extinction)

Answer (score 0):

**survival**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/survival)

> a. act or process of surviving  b. state or fact of continuing to live
>   or exist b. fact of having survived.